# How do I replace certain pieces in a string in a list in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bioinformatics

```
['Parent=transcript:Zm00001d034962_T001', 'Parent=transcript:Zm00001d034962_T002', 'Parent=transcript:Zm00001d034962_T003', 'Parent=transcript:Zm00001d034962_T003', 'Parent=transcript:Zm00001d034962_T004', 'Parent=transcript:Zm00001d034962_T005', 'Parent=transcript:Zm00001d034962_T005', 'Parent=transcript:Zm00001d034962_T005']
```

This is what it looks like.

I would like to replace `Parent=transcript:` and `_T00`

please help. not sure what command to use

Comment: You want to replace them with what? This is a list and you will need a for loop to iterate over it

Answer (score 1):

Use python's built-in `replace()` function. For the last part, if it's always 5 characters you can easily exclude them:

```
items = [
    'Parent=transcript:Zm00001d034962_T001',
    'Parent=transcript:Zm00001d034962_T002',
    'Parent=transcript:Zm00001d034962_T003',
    'Parent=transcript:Zm00001d034962_T003', 
    'Parent=transcript:Zm00001d034962_T004', 
    'Parent=transcript:Zm00001d034962_T005', 
    'Parent=transcript:Zm00001d034962_T005', 
    'Parent=transcript:Zm00001d034962_T005'
]

# use enumerate to replace the item in the list
for index, item in enumerate(items):
    # this replaces the items with an empty string, deleting it
    new_item = item.replace('Parent=transcript:', '')
    # this accesses all the characters in the string minus the last 5
    new_item = new_item[0:len(new_item) - 5] + "whatever you want to replace that with"
    # replace the item in the list
    items[index] = new_item
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want to replace the following strings to `''`

Replace `Parent=transcript:` to `''`

Replace `_T00` to `''`

For example,
`'Parent=transcript:Zm00001d034962_T001'` will get replaced as `'Zm00001d0349621'`.

The ending string `1` from `_T001` will get concatenated to `Zm00001d034962`.

If that is your expected result, the code is:

```
new_list = [x.replace('Parent=transcript:','').replace('_T00','') for x in input_list]
print (new_list)
```

The output of `new_list` will be:

```
['Zm00001d0349621', 'Zm00001d0349622', 'Zm00001d0349623', 'Zm00001d0349623', 'Zm00001d0349624', 'Zm00001d0349625', 'Zm00001d0349625', 'Zm00001d0349625']
```

Note you can replace `''` with whatever you want the new string to be. I have marked it as `''` as I don't know what your new replaced string will be.